# SignInActivity Microsoft graph is not working anymore

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

SignInActivity is not working even though we have Azure Premium 2 in our tenant.
I have  "AuditLog.Read.All" and usng application permissions
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity

Comment: What error are you getting? - attach the request id and timestamp. Also explain how have you acquired the access token you are using to access the endpoint? The query above is working in my tenant.

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": "Authentication_RequestFromNonPremiumTenantOrB2CTenant",
        "message": "Neither tenant is B2C or tenant doesn't have premium license",
        
    }
} we do have premiumn p1 and p2 for our azure ad. Do i need to add directory.read.all permission as well

Comment: Please attach the request id and timestamp if any

Comment: the issue got resolved, it seems we need directory.read.all permission as well, to fetch license information i.e p1 ,p2